# SASS: How to install a custom built Compass extension

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am creating my own Compass extension following [this tutorial](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/extensions/). (I am using terminal on Mac 10.9)

I have built my extension using the command `gem build myextension.gemspec`
The terminal states: `Successfully built RubyGem`

I then install my extension using  `sudo gem install myextension-1.0.gem`
The terminal states: `Successfully installed myextension-1.0 1 gem installed`

I then check the installation using `gem list framework`. The gem doesn't appear, which is odd.

Next in my SASS project, I call the gem in my config.rb file:

```
require "myextension"
```

Finally, I call it in my scss file:

```
@import "myextension";
```

Yet compass keeps on saying it can't find my extension. 
What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried using [this template](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Compass-Extension-Template) and following the steps exactly, but it keeps on failing.

I know about Code-kit, but I would like to do this via an extension for easier sharing.

---

Update:

I download the template again and duplicated it to create two extensions folders.
In both of them, I added in my Scss.

For the first one, I left all file names as they are in the template.

I did build/install and got the same results as above.

For the second one, I changed all instances of "extension" to "myextension" and did build. This time, I got this error message during the build (which I hadn't got in the past).

```
Invalid gemspec in [myextension.gemspec]: /Users/myusername/Sites/test1-ext/myextension/lib/myextension.rb:19: class/module name must be CONSTANT
ERROR:  Error loading gemspec. Aborting.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this message. I have looked at line 19 of myextension.rb, but there is nothing to do with a class/module name (the modulename in this file is set to myextension, except for line 10 & 11 with the words `extension_path`, but even if I rename this I get the same error message).

I have uploaded my extension [here](http://madhu.co/web/stackoverflow/myextension.zip)

Comment: Double check all of the locations where the extension name is referenced.  I've had extensions fail to load because of this.

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks!, I've checked it carefully but the same problem. I've even downloaded the sass team template and left the name as "extension". Is there anyway I can check the extension is installed. I have run `gem list framework`, but it doesn't appear on the list (even though it says it has installed when I use `sudo gem install`). Are there any other templates I can try installing? (I have tried `compass create my_extension --using compass/extension -x scss`. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: @cimmanon Once you have built and installed a gem, how do you call it with in a new sass project. I am using `@import "myextension";` (I have already declared  `require "myextension"` in config.rb).

Comment: You're referencing it correctly within your project.  Double check the names used in the gemspec and lib/extension.rb of your extension.

Comment: @cimmanon I've tried downloading the template (from tema sass) and just sticking with their name of `extension`, but its the same problem. Would you be able to upload one of the gems you have made and I can have a look and see if I am doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You've definitely restarted your watch command since the config.rb was modified?  Have you tried using your extension ad hoc (I run mine ad hoc in project just for testing extensions)?

Comment: @cimmanon I have updated my post with more information.

Comment: I don't think spaces are allowed, typically hyphens are used if the extension's name has more than one word in it.

Comment: @cimmanon I haven't used spaces in my filename (That's just a typo in the post, which I have now corrected!)